# Using axios inside an express route is returning special characters instead of json in data field

Tags: node.js, json, express, axios

I have been trying to fix this issue for a pretty long time, I would appreciate the help.

I have tried using the nodeJs library of Moralis it worked on my local but did not on dev server was returning undefined, so I came back to axios;

I tried changing header type.

Tried using .send instead of .json

Tried puting the response in status(200)

Tried sending it as full response

Console.log(response) has the same result from the terminal

---

This is the route and the axios inside

```
import express from "express";
import axios from 'axios';
import { chainIdAliases, wrappedNatives } from "../constants";
import { envVars } from "../server";

const moralis = express.Router();

moralis.get('/get_user_tokens/', (req, res): any => {
    const { address, chainId }: any = req.query
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/${address}/erc20`,
        params: { chain: chainIdAliases[chainId] },
        headers: { accept: 'application/json', 'X-API-Key': envVars.MORALIS }
    };
    axios.request(options)
        .then((response) => {
            res.status(200).json(response.data)
        }).catch((error) => {
            res.status(400).json(error);
        });
});


export default moralis
```

And this is the result Im getting

```
data: '\x1F�\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03��OK\x031\x10��RrRXJ�N�=�B�"Bۓ�L&I[��H�Ŋ����t�\n' +
    '�9�\x0E��{��v�)u�\x18�6�=�\x19?P\x06���6F@\rZb\x02�6\x03*�\x109\x05rJ�g\x15�M�f�٤\x1C�1��U�\x7FmCi~�MY\x15Vw����n�oC���k��6-6=���X�\x06;��\x0B��cu�-�����\x04y��Y\x02\x10�\x04��a\n' +
    "\\\x07��'��]�_�\x16i�N��r>\x1D�����n\x18�-���/J\x13�O�\x04Dc\x1D\x00�L�8�*ȔT��t\x16d�I��L\x16�]\ru�����_e�R\t1��\f�;�5D�*��$\r�\x1C�p|Pv�m�\x17|\x1E}\x16�����R�\x14F\x1B�\x11�z����\x1D\x00\x00��\x03\x00R\x1A9!�\x02\x00\x00
```

When I use the same function in my client, it works like a charm, that`s why I think this is about Express or body-parser, any other endpoint in my app which doesn't use axios works fine.

This is the express.ts

```
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import express from "express";
import helmet from "helmet";
import morgan from "morgan";

// Routes
import moralis from "./routes/moralis";
import receipts from "./routes/receipts";

const init = () => {
    //initialize app
    const app = express();
    // adding Helmet to enhance your API's security
    app.use(helmet());
    // Bodyparser middleware
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    // adding morgan to log HTTP requests
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    // Routes
    app.use("/api/receipts", receipts);
    app.use("/api/moralis", moralis);
    return app;
};

export default init
```

And this is the server.ts

```
import { createServer } from "http";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import init from './express';
import dotenv from "dotenv"; 

dotenv.config()
// Export Env Vars
export const envVars = {
  MORALIS: process.env.MORALIS_API_SECRET
}
//Init Server
const server = createServer(init());
//establish socket.io connection
const io = new Server(server);
io.of('/socket').on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('socket.io: User connected: ', socket.id);

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('socket.io: User disconnected: ', socket.id);
  });
});
//Port Config
const port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ? 5000 : process.env.PORT;
//start the server
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server up and running at port ${port} !`);
});
// DB Config
const db = process.env.MONGO_URI as string;
// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(db, {});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log('MongoDB successfully connected')
  console.log('Setting change streams');
  //Listen to new Receipts
  const receiptsChangeStream = connection.collection('receipts').watch();
  receiptsChangeStream.on('change', (change: any) => {
    const { from, to, txHash } = change.fullDocument
    switch (change.operationType) {
      case 'insert':
        io.of('/socket').emit('newReceipt', { from, to, txHash });
        break;
    }
  });
});
connection.on('error', (error) => console.log('Error: ' + error));
//On New Pending Receipt
export const emitPending = (newPending: any) => {
  io.of('/socket').emit('newPending', newPending);
}
```

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser.json());` Just try use this one only for the bodyParser

Comment: @DreamBold I have tried, its the same

Comment: Did you compare the exact url and request headers between axios and a client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In v1.2.1 fixed this error.

You need to add `Accept-Encoding` with `application/json` in axios.get header.

It is [known defect.](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298)

The default of it is gzip in `axios` v1.2.0

using this option for axios get call

```
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/${address}/erc20`,
        params: { chain: chainIdAliases[chainId] },
        headers: {
              accept: 'application/json',
              'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
             'X-API-Key': envVars.MORALIS,
        }
    };
```