# Get API foreign key relation with Axios in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, axios, get, vuejs3

**Context :**

I make an API with API-Platform, and I consume this API with Vue 3 and HTTP client Axios

I have two entities in my API :

- **Author** : name(string)
- **Text** : content(string), author(relation to **Author**)

So a text item is relate to an Author...

**Problem :**

In Vue 3,  I want to call my API for get **Text** entity.
But in the author column (`<td> {{ item.author }} </td>`) i have juste the URI reference (*/api/authors/2*) but I need the name of author...

**Solution I tried :**

```html
<td> {{ getAuthor(item.author) }} </td>
```

(authorLink = /api/authors/2)

```js
methods: {
  getAuthor: async function (authorLink){

    const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000' + authorLink)
    console.log(res.data.name)
    return res.data.name

  }
```

**Result of my solution :**

With console.log() : 'JohnDoe' -> this work !

With return : '"[object Promise]"' -> this didnt work..

Comment: You could replace the line with the `return` by something like this `this.name = res.data.name` directly. No need to `return` anything into a `methods`, it is more aimed towards `computed()`.

Comment: I tried to with `this.name = res.data.name`, the result is same : "[object Promise]" ¨...

Answer (score 1):

This way to get the return name with async/await pattern.

And axios needs a `Accept-Encoding` with correct format.

```
const getAuthor = async () => {
...
   const res = await axios.get(...);
   return Promise.resolve(res.data.name);
};

getAuthor()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
```

Demo code

```
const axios = require("axios");

const getAuthor = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                }
            }
        );
        return Promise.resolve(res.data.name);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
};

getAuthor()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Result this code

```
$ node get-data.js
Leanne Graham
```

This is express server version

```
const express = require("express")
const axios = require("axios")
const cors = require("cors")

const PORT = 3030

const app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cors())

const getAuthor = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                }
            }
        );
        return Promise.resolve(res.data.name);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
};

app.get("/users/:id", async (req, res) => {
    getAuthor()
        .then(result => {
            res.json(result)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
})

app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
    if (err)
        console.log("Error in server setup")
    console.log("Server listening on Port", PORT);
})
```

install dependencies

```
npm install express axios cors
```

run it

```
$ node data-server.js
Server listening on Port 3030
```

Open this URL Chrome and open DevTool by F12

```
http://localhost:3030/users/1
```

[image]

Comment: I can't use this header : DevTools console say me "Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding""

Comment: axios v1.2.0 has defect, if not add `Accept-Encoding` in header, the return data is not get readable data.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633358/using-axios-inside-an-express-route-is-returning-special-characters-instead-of-j/74634364#74634364

Comment: Which DevTools is using?

Comment: Chrome DevTools

Comment: @user18419618, I add a Chrome Dev Tool. It's express sever and show auth name without problem.